Terminate debugging automatically before build in VSCode
When I trigger a build for the target exe, it will fail if that exe is under debugging.
Is it possible to terminate debugging automatically before build?

find the commandID that is linked with the stop debugging command, use a redefinition of F5 key binding and use runCommands to first stop debugging and then run task or launch

@rioV8 nit: that will only affect the keybinding. not anything else, such as integration to common menu contributions, or custom buttons or action buttons.
